# NO fruit on my Hybrid orange/lemon tree

Tags: diagnosis

why do i not get any blooms on my hybrid fruit trees? live in south fl. has ample sun, gets plenty of H2O! has ground cover under the tree. tree is 4-5 yrs old. did have some fruit 2yrs ago??????

Comment: Greetings @user20713 and welcome to G&L. Please take the tour gardening.stackexchange.com/tour to get familiar with concept of Q&A on this site.
Regarding your question, adding more information about species and few images of those trees to your question would be helpful.

Comment: No picture, no answer.

Comment: There are so many reasons. We really need more information and pictures. Fertilizers? Pruning? Disease? Soil pH? soil structure? too much water? or just to early (5 years is a small period to carry fruits on wild plants, OTOH commercial varieties are quicker) (and possibly many more causes).